# How to create the custom attribute in react 15?

Tags: reactjs, attributes

How to add a custom attribute in `<div variant="variant1"/></div>` in React 15 version?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Maybe give an example.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried and specify what outcome you expect and what result you get. Right now it is hard to understand what the question is.